# Where integration bots are stored?

Tags: xcode, macos, continuous-integration, osx-server

Where does OSX Server store integration bots? Or is it my local Xcode who stores them? Server screwed my setup again, but this time I'm no longer able to see my bots.

Just want to express my deep frustration with Xcode CI:

OSX Server (or whatever it's called) is one of a kind piece of software, giving me incredible headaches lately with its' laginness, bugginess and poor performance. I think over the past week I experienced all possible errors Server has to offer:

- "internal error updating bot" (please try again later);
- "error reading service configuration" (or similar wording) - requires Xcode reset; continue to occur randomly again and again with no reasons;
- "Xcode version is not supported" - only reboot seems to convince server to use Xcode which was already used previously
- Randomly, fail integrations because "device is not connected", given that I test desktop application for OSX...
- Finally, after yet another episode of screwing my setup, I no longer can see my bots on the server - they vanished. well done Server.

Answer (score 1):

The bots and integrations are stored on the server.
The directory should look something like `/Users/<xcode_server_tester_user_name>/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots`
(OSX-Server 5.3 (16S4123), XCode 8.3.2 (8E2002))

- I hate to say this but I found restarting the machine is a good way to resolve frustration No. 1 and 2.
- `device is not connected` error often happens right after OS, OSX-Server or XCode is upgraded.

  - Usually reselecting devices from the XCode UI works for me.
    [image]
    Although sometimes it may require repeating multiple times and waiting for a long time for the device list to load.
  - On your OSX Server machine, deleting the simulator and re-adding it via `Xcode->Devices` sometimes helps too.
  - Another way is to delete all simulators from the linked Xcode on OSX Server machine and only keep the ones you want to test your project on. Config the bot to use `All iOS Devices and Simulators`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Xcode Server now runs as a specific user, the configuration files are kept in `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer`.  You can also hit the [Xcode Server API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeServerAPIReference/Integrations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016472-CH3-SW1) to get information about your bots.

Answer (score 0):

In a Couchbase db.

I don't know how to access the contents though.

Enter this in Safari on your server

http://localhost:10355/_utils/